# Drag div with an <audio></audio> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know if it is possbile drag a div that have `200px` and a `<audio></audio>` element into a droppable area, and when the div is dropped the `div` changes the size, to have the size according to the sound duration (`1px` per second for example)?

https://jsfiddle.net/hfy3dwf5/4/

code without the div size part:

```
$(function() {   
     $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
      });
      $(".drop").droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {

        }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i didn't get your problem statement wrong, you could try the following

```
$(".drop").droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui){
       var audlen = $('audio').duration;
       $(ui.draggable).css({width:audlen + 'px'});
   }
});
```